# Is the orthogonal projection of a bounded point bounded?

Tags: projection

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded point ($||v||\leq M$ for some $M>0$) and $C$ be a closed set.

Is $y \in P_C(v)$ a bounded point (it may not be unique when $C$ is not convex) where $P_C(x)=\arg\min_{z\in C} ||z-v||^2$?

---

**My intuition**:

I know the orthogonal projection cannot expand things so a bounded point stays bounded but I do not know how to show it.
Also, I know the orthogonal projection is continuous (correct me if I am wrong) and I think the image of a bounded point under a continuous map is bounded. If that is the case I am done.

Comment: What is your definition of "bounded point"?

Comment: What is $P_C$? Your definition is wrong as it stands.

Comment: Every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded. If the set $C$ is non empty then since $\|z-v\| \le \|z\| + \|v\|$ we see that $\|y\| \le \inf_{z \in C} \|z\| + \|v\|$.